# Border animation on hover

Tags: html, css

I was wondering, how can I create an effect like this, where the user mouse over a box and the border follow his mouse position when hovering other boxes?
I tried to search for similar examples and I couldn't find anything.

mouse hover:

[image]

Comment: Try using Javascript to control another div. Move it and resize it according to the target box which mouse hovered.

Comment: Here is a tutorial for a pretty similar effect [link](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/), its not new but it works

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Why people down vote a normal question?

Comment: You're getting downvoted because of the lack of research this question shows. The essence of this question boils down to "Here's a gif, write the code for me". What would make this question better is if you'd add a snippet of code, showcasing your efforts, and explaining what you've tried to accomplish the goal. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I create a [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/9o3f2bpu/60/)!
Maybe this is what you want :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navBar = $('#navBar');
  var perNav = $('#navBar nav');
  var borderBlock = $('#navBar #imBorder');

  /* onHover events */
  perNav.hover(

    //mouseover
    function() {
      //Get the positionX of nav which is hovered.
      //Then turn the value to Integer
      var offsetX = $(this).position().left;

      /* #imBorder change positionX and fadeIn */
      borderBlock.css({
        'transform': 'translateX(' + offsetX + 'px)',
        'opacity': '1'
      })
    },

    //mouseout
    function() {
      /* #imBorder fadeOut */
      borderBlock.css({
        'opacity': '0'
      })
    }
  );

})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #444;
}

#navBar {
  display: block;
  width: 324px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  position: relative;
}

#navBar #imBorder {
  pointer-events: none;
  /* Prevent #imBorder block on top when hovered */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 102px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #fff;
  /* for animation */
  transition: transform 250ms ease, opacity 300ms ease;
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 0;
}

#navBar>nav {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navBar">
  <div id="imBorder"></div>
  <nav>button1</nav>
  <nav>button2</nav>
  <nav>button3</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I just noticed that it won't work in the Y axis, like if you put more `nav` it will only work on the first row, you can hover the second row.